# How do you toggle a DC current on/off with a input?

Tags: current, circuit-design, components, component-selection, toggle-switch

I'm new to circuitry and am planning on making a 12V DC circuit soon. I'm currently making plans & getting supplies, and was just wondering if there's some sort of component that would not allow the current to flow from one end to another without a separate input to come in, which then, it would allow the current to flow, essentially like a toggle switch, except instead of a switch, it's an input.

Comment: A relay?.......

Comment: A MOSFET could do this too.

Comment: A relay is essentially an electrically-operated switch.

Comment: You should explain your question better.

Comment: It is obvious you lack knowledge of what your doing, so to keep it simple and avoid shock hazards I would use a relay.

Answer (score 0):

If you are limiting yourself to solid state components and avoiding contacts from switches or relays, a simple SCS  (silicon controlled switch) would work. Most designers have use SCRs (silicon controlled rectifiers), but they switch on and never switch off until power is removed. But an SCS can be pulsed to switch on and pulsed to switch off. SCRs and SCSs are often used when higher power is required. Wikipedia offers a more detailed explanation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_controlled_rectifier

It starts out with SCRs but subsequently goes into detail about SCSs. These devices are really thyristers (4 layer semiconductors) and probably should more correctly be called "semiconductor-controlled-rectifier" and "semiconductor-controlled-switch".